# How to force google reader app to download mp3s

Tags: mp3, podcast, google-reader

When I subscribe to podcast RSS feeds with the google reader app then click the link to the mp3 Google reader starts streaming it with the selected media player rather than downloading the mp3 file to the sdcard like the webbrowser does.

Is there anyway to force it to download the actual mp3 file?

Comment: I'd try clearing the defaults for either/both Google Reader and the media player under `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, then see if it will prompt you how you want to handle the link.

Answer (score 4):

For listening to podcasts, Google has a separate application, called [Google Listen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.listen&hl=en), which will sync feeds under the Listen Subscriptions category. Unfortunately, new features are not being actively added, but does provide enough functionality to be useful.

Comment: Why would you say it's not well maintained, it's had a number of updates with bug-fixes and compatility fixes this year, and I've never had issues with it?

Comment: You're right, @GAThrawn, it's not that they are not maintaining it, but new features are not being actively added. It hasn't been even been updated for the ICS look. I'll update the answers.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then. Personally the fact that it hasn't turned into a bloated, do-everything app is what I like about it. It does one thing and does just what I need. If you want a complicated, bloated app with a million settings and features, they're out there, but luckily Listen isn't trying to be one of them.

Comment: Something as simple as lock-screen controls is missing. That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up buying an app called doggcatcher it has a ton of great features and for podcasts it works much better than Google reader, I highly recommend it.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your issue, but this isn't an answer to the original question.